# Query select columns with GORM

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

```
func GetShopCategory(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var shopCategories []model.ShopCategory
    err := model.DB.Select("ID","Name","Slug").Find(&shopCategories)
    if err.Error != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusNoContent)
    }
    return c.JSON(shopCategories)
}
```

I have a shop_category table. I want to show all table with selected columns like "ID","Name","Slug" only. so how can I response table's data with only these column. i don't wanna show other columns name.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with '[Smart Select Fields](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#smart_select)'

```golang
type APIShopCategory struct {
    ID uint
    Name string
    Slug string
}


func GetShopCategory(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var shopCategories []APIShopCategory
    err := model.DB.Model(&model.ShopCategory{}).Find(&shopCategories)
    if err.Error != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusNoContent)
    }
    return c.JSON(shopCategories)
}
```

Comment: thank you Eloib. you make my day.